# RAD Studio operation error during community edition iinstall

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I'm trying to install RAD Studio on Windows 10. I have the community edition and a license code for it. Every time I attempt to install I get the following error:

[image]

I have no idea why this happening and can't find anything via Google or their forums. Can't find any reference to actionID codes.

Delphi 10.3 seems to be installed, but it's incomplete as the only type of file it allows me to create is a .txt file. No Delphi related stuff:

[image]

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: How hard have you looked?  Try googling **Delphi 10.3 "operation error"**.

Comment: My googlefu sucks. I was using "RAD Studio operation error". Thanks, will dig through these now. I have already done a full clean manually following instructions from Embarcadero and also tried CCcleaner.

Comment: The other thing is thatISTR there is a way of turning off the events feed, which judging by the "Error parsing events feed" msg *might* be a way of silencing the error.

Comment: Headache. Still no joy. Been trying to install this for 2 days now.

Comment: I grabbed ISO, mounted, and installed that way. Works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get Delphi 10.3 installed via the web installer. Instead I logged into my account and downloaded the ISO. I mounted with [gBurner Virtual Drive](http://www.gburner.com/online-help/virtual-drive.htm) and installed.

If you're on windows 10 you do not need gBurner VD. Thanks to @whosrdaddy in the comments:

> if you have Windows 10, no need for a virtual drive software, just
>   right click the ISO and select "mount"

Everything is working fine.

[image]

Comment: small nitpick, if you have Windows 10, no need for a virtual drive software, just right click the ISO and select "mount"

Comment: TIL. I've been a Linux user for too long I'm still learning Windows.